# Angularjs filter or json formating?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently learning angularjs, and I'm blocked with this one.
Considering this json structure in my controller's scope :

```
var days = {
    "0":{
        "date":"2015-08-06",
        "data":[
            { "_id":"1", "a":"FOO", "b":"BAR", "id":"77" },
            { "_id":"1", "a":"dummy", "b":"data", "id":"22" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"foo", "b":"bar", "id":"12" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"DUMMY", "b":"DATA", "id":"124" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"HELLO", "b":"WORLD", "id":"35" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"hello", "b":"world", "id":"35" }
        ] 
    },
    "1":{
        "date":"2015-08-07",
        "data":[
            { "_id":"1", "a":"john", "b":"doe", "id":"2" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"JOHN", "b":"DOE", "id":"55" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"bruce", "b":"lee", "id":"241" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"BRUCE", "b":"LEE", "id":"321" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"bruce", "b":"wayne", "id":"45" }
        ]
    }
};

var infos = {
    "1": {"aa":"Message from infos 1"},
    "2": {"aa":"Message from infos 2"},
    "3": {"aa":"Message from infos 3"}
};
```

what would be the best way to use this json in my view to obtain something like that :

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
    <h2>{{day.date}}</h2>
    <!-- 
        here for each value of day.data._id, I'd would like a new list 
        so for the first day.data it would be
    -->
    <div>  <!-- _id = 1 -->
        <h3>
            <!-- here, the message from infos.1.aa -->
        </h3>
        <ul> 
            <li>FOO BAR</li>
            <li>dummy data</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div> <!-- _id = 2 -->
        <h3>
           <!-- here, the message from infos.2.aa --> 
        </h3>
        <ul> 
            <li>foo bar</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div> <!-- _id = 3 -->
        <h3>
            <!-- here, the message from infos.3.aa -->
        </h3>
        <ul> 
            <li>DUMMY DATA</li>
            <li>HELLO WORLD</li>
            <li>hello world</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would it be best to use custom filters or modify the data?

I can't figure how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For presenting data in a DOM - you should not extend filters for that. Use custom directives instead - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I forgot to precise that my data are fetched via $http. Is that possible to use $http with custom directive?

Comment: $http as a data-handling layer and directives as presentation layer can and should be used together, independently from each other

Comment: Well this is definitevelly something I have to deal with in depth ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its not the best way but you can try with this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ODl5txALU1V8drxbQeE2?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
    <h2>{{day.date}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in day.data | groupBy: '_id'">
        <h3>
            {{infos[value].aa}}
        </h3>
        <ul> 
            <li ng-repeat="data in day.data | filter: {_id: value}">{{data.a}} {{data.b}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

FILTER:

```
var uniqueItems = function (data, key) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i][key];
        if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
};


app.filter('groupBy', function () {
    return function (collection, key) {
        if (collection === null) return;
        return uniqueItems(collection, key);
    };
});
```

JSON DATA:

```
$scope.days = {
    "0":{
        "date":"2015-08-06",
        "data":[
            { "_id":"1", "a":"FOO", "b":"BAR", "id":"77" },
            { "_id":"1", "a":"dummy", "b":"data", "id":"22" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"foo", "b":"bar", "id":"12" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"DUMMY", "b":"DATA", "id":"124" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"HELLO", "b":"WORLD", "id":"35" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"hello", "b":"world", "id":"35" }
        ] 
    },
    "1":{
        "date":"2015-08-07",
        "data":[
            { "_id":"1", "a":"john", "b":"doe", "id":"2" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"JOHN", "b":"DOE", "id":"55" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"bruce", "b":"lee", "id":"241" },
            { "_id":"2", "a":"BRUCE", "b":"LEE", "id":"321" },
            { "_id":"3", "a":"bruce", "b":"wayne", "id":"45" }
        ]
    }
};

$scope.infos = {
    "1": {"aa":"Message from infos 1"},
    "2": {"aa":"Message from infos 2"},
    "3": {"aa":"Message from infos 3"}
};
```

Comment: Thank you nada, looks like this is what I was looking for!